# Possible to overlay a Button on top of another?

Tags: android, button, overlay

I am trying to overlay a sort of button on top of another button.  The reason being I want to explain to the user what certain buttons will do.

**For example:**
There will be a button. In the top right or whatever of that button there will be a question mark. When the user presses the question mark it will explain what that button does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a Relative Layout. Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html It'll let you overlay.

Relativelayout will let you align images beside each other easily as well as on top of each other.

Why don't you make the RelativeLayout your button and put your question mark inside it, align it to the right or something.. e.g

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/mybutton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@style/icon"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can attach listeners to both.

Comment: I've been working with relative layout I havent found any way to implement it the way I want it.

Comment: could you post some code? and exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: the code is straightforward its a relatiivelayout with buttons inside it, however I want a question mark button, image whatever on top of those buttons and when the user clicks on that (question mark) part of the button it explains what it does.

Comment: "Relativelayout will let you align images beside each other easily as well as on top of each other." It only allows you to place them above eachother not ON eachother or within

Comment: Check my updated answer, let me know if I still haven't answered you

Answer (score 12):

That's what came to mind, try it:

```
   <RelativeLayout>
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"/>
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnOne"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/btnOne"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Apart from wrong formatting that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: Yes this works well. Now you can assign 2 buttons and have them flip flop back and fourth based on program logic

Comment: Thanks!  This worked great as a way to fade from one color button to another through alpha animation.  Over time if the data is stall I wanted the button to fade to a grey "unknown" state.  But I would note, that I added alignRight and alignBottom as well so the buttons were 100% overlapping.